Can I use optical amplifier to extend the distance between my server and SAN?
I have a server with fiber channel Host Bus Adapter(FC-HBA) connecting to SAN. The HBA can be either 8Gbps supporting up to 190 meters distance to the SAN, or 16Gbps supporting up to 125 meters. However, the SAN is 300 meters away. Can I use optical amplifier in between to extend the distance so that the HBA works with the SAN? Or is there any other approach to make it work?

Reach with multi-mode fiber isn't just about attenuation, it's also about dispersion. Extending reach would mean intermediate regeneration, ie. a switch, or an extender with two SFPs.
A cheaper and less complex alternative to full regeneration is to use a PHY that's suitable for >300 m reach. You can just swap the SFPs for 800-SM-LC-I or 1600-SM-LZ-I to support up to 1.4/2 km of single-mode fiber.

Thanks for your answer. I am new to fiber networking, the server I am referring to is a Solace appliance, the HBA spec: https://docs.solace.com/Appliance/3560-Hardware-Installation/ADB-and-HBA-Specs-and-Cabling.htm
The Optical Loss Budget and Operating Distances: https://docs.solace.com/Appliance/3560-Hardware-Installation/Optical-Fibre-Specs.htm#optical_fibre_specs_1316714465_141216
The SFP modules on ADBs and associated HBAs use LC connectors for Fibre Channel connections using shortwave laser optics over MMF cable.
Can the proposed PHY and single-mode fiber work with it?

Seems the vendor only supports MMF, bummer. I'd contact their support for what options you have.
